# Finding such $u(x,y)$ that satisfies this differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am having a hard time finding such $u(x,y)$ that satisfies partial differential equation
$$\frac\partial{\partial y}(u_x+u)+2x^2y(u_x+u)=0.$$

Here is everything I know so far:
We need to set up $v(x,y)=u_x+u$. I am stuck at this point onwards.

Comment: In your rewrite it looks like you applied $\frac\partial{\partial y}$ to all the remaining terms, but in what you call the partial differential equation it is only applied to part of the remaining terms. Should there be an external pair of parentheses around the entire thing, so that your rewrite is correct?

Comment: What is $f(u)$?

Comment: @Gonçalo Function of u?

Comment: Hint : Change of function $v(x,y)=(u_x+u)$

Comment: @JJacquelin Thank you for the hint. Could you please explain the motivation? I am confused about how it would change the result.

Comment: @Bagaringa, it's still unclear. What function of $u$? What $f(u)$ has to do with the solution to the PDE?

Comment: I got this question on a problem sheet, and this is the exact statement. So I suppose we just need to find such $f(u)$ when $u(x,y)$ to satisfies the equation? I am not really sure about that, that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: Please attach an image of the problem sheet. Without context, one cannot say anything about $f(u)$.

Comment: @Gonçalo I am afraid this is all I have. It is based on the syllabus of average introduction to differential equations class for physicists, so I assume it's not supposed to be too technical or advanced. With the information as stated only, what is the most likely inference one could possibly make about the problem? I am not a mathematician, so this question is unfortunately harder for me to answer.

Comment: The best one can do here is help you to solve the PDE, but one cannot find $f(u)$ without knowing its definition.

Comment: @Gonçalo Thank you for your patience, I've been informed by my professor that there's a type in my problem statement. What we need to find is just $u(x,y)$ that satisfies this equation. I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac\partial{\partial y}(u_x+u)+2x^2y(u_x+u)=0.$$
To answer to the comment request :
$$v(x,y)=(u_x+u)$$
$$v_y+2x^2y\:v=0$$
This is a first order ODE since there is no $v_x$ into it.
$$\frac{1}{v}\frac{dv}{dy}=-2x^2y$$
Integrate wrt $y$ :
$$\ln|v|=-x^2y^2+\text{ an arbitrary constant wrt }y \text{ but function of }x$$
$$v(x,y)=f(x)\: e^{-2x^2y^2}$$
$f(x)$ is an arbitrary function which is a constant of integration wrt $y$.
$$v=u_x+u=f(x)\: e^{-2x^2y^2}$$
$$\frac{du}{dx}+u=f(x)\: e^{-2x^2y^2}$$
This is a first order linear ODE for $u$ wrt $x$. Solving leads to
$$u(x,y)=e^{-x}\int e^xf(x)\: e^{-2x^2y^2}dx+e^{-x}g(y)$$
$g(y)$ is an arbitrary function.

Without boundary condition one cannot determine $f(x)$ and $g(y)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Recently, I've been informed that there's indeed a typo in my problem statement and I've updated my question respectively. What we need to find is such $u(x,y)$ that satisfies the differential equation. Could you kindly answer how does it change your proposed solution, if at all?

Comment: My answer gives the solution.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible by any chance to simplify this integral $e^{-x}\int e^xf(x)\mathrm{~}e^{-2x^2y^2}dx+g(y)$ or no, considering that we consider $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be some constants/constant functions, if we don't have boundary conditions?

Comment: Additionally, do you mind answering if the method you used is commonly known in English as variation of constants or parameters, by any chance?

Comment: One cannot simplify the integral until $f(x)$ be explicitly known. Of course you can set $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ as arbitrary constants. But this provides only particular solutions of the PDE, not the general solution. OK. the last ODE was solved thanks to the method of "variation of parameters".

Comment: Thanks, as I now practice this, I noticed that using variation of parameters I am getting a slightly different answer. Could you update the solution to the last ODE with writing some intermediary steps? It'd make me sure I am not misunderstanding something.

Comment: What is the slightly different answer that you get ?